# Understanding η-conversion (Lambda Calculus)

Tags: functions, lambda-calculus

Let $h \in A\rightarrow (B\rightarrow C)$
I'm trying to understand the following reduction:

$$\lambda x\in A. \lambda y \in B.(h(x))(y) \\= \lambda x\in A.h(x) \\= h$$

Apparently, this is done by using "Eta-Reduction". Can you help me understand the use of this rule here?

Comment: I really don't know what I'm talking about, but using [this](http://www.lambda-bound.com/book/lambdacalc/node21.html) link, to the first step take $\lambda y.My$ as $\lambda y\in B.(h(x))(y)$ and perform $\eta$-reduction to on this formula to get $$\lambda x\in A. \lambda y \in B.(h(x))(y) \underset{\eta}{\longrightarrow} \lambda x\in A.h(x)$$ (because $\lambda y\in B.(h(x))(y)\underset{\eta}{\longrightarrow} h(x)$). Similarly $\lambda x\in A.h(x) \underset{\eta}{\longrightarrow}h$.

Comment: I repeat, I don't know what I'm talking about, but to me $$\lambda x\in A. \lambda y \in B.(h(x))(y) \underset{\eta}{\longrightarrow} \lambda y\in B.h(y)\underset{\eta}{\longrightarrow} h$$ feels better somehow.

Comment: @GitGud Your first comment seems to be the right answer, but I can't understand your second comment. You seem to be $\eta$-converting a function with domain $A$ to a function with domain $B$ and then back to a function with domain $A$. Surely, $\eta$-conversion (or anything that deserves to be called "conversion") preserves types.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thank you for the input. I wasn't sure $h$ is a function, my motivation for the second comment was too look at $(h(x))(y)$ as a predicate - (I have no idea if *predicate* is a $\lambda$-calculus term or not) - first as a predicate depending on $x$, so I eliminate $x$ first. Then a predicate on $y$ remains and I eliminate $y$.

Comment: It took me a few seconds, but then it hit me. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Consider some function $F$.  This function takes an argument $x$ and yields $F x$.

Now consider the following function $G$: $$\lambda y. F y$$ This function *also* takes an argument $x$ and yields $F x$.

$G$ and $F$ might be completely different lambda-terms, but it is the case that $Fx=Gx$ for every $x$, so the functions represented by $F$ and $G$ are equal.

For example, consider $$\begin{align}
F & = \lambda x.x \\
G & = \lambda x.(\lambda y.y)x \\
\end{align}$$

$F$ is the identity function.  $G$ is the function that takes an argument $x$ and applies the identity function to it.  $F$ is not the same term as $G$: One is four symbols long, the other ten symbols.  But the behavior of $F$ and $G$ is the same, in the sense that for every term $x$, $F x $ has a normal form if and only if $ G x$ does, and if so these normal forms are the same.

When this happens, we say that $F$ and $G$ are $\eta$-equivalent, or that $F$ is the $\eta$-reduction of $G$, or that $G$ is the $\eta$-expansion of $F$, or that $F$ and $G$ are $\eta$-conversions of one another.

Comment: This reminds me of the warning I get in Haskell when I define a function f which takes n parameters and just calls a function g with the same n parameters.

Answer (score 7):

For **Eta reduction**, see Hendrik Pieter Barendregt, [The Lambda Calculus Its Syntax and Semantics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0444875085)  (rev ed - 1984), page 63 :

> **3.3.1. Definition** : (i) $\eta:\lambda x.Mx \rightarrow M$ provided $x \notin FV(M)$.
>
> The point of $\beta \eta$-reduction is that it axiomatizes provable equality in the
> extensional $\lambda$-calculus.

This amount to saying that, whenever the function $M$ is to be used, any argument will simply be passed to $M$. Hence, this function is, in essence, equal to $M$. One caveat of $\eta$-abstraction is that a name conflict must be avoided. What this means is if $x$ is a free variable (i.e., not scoped in a function abstraction) in $M$ itself, then this $\eta$-reduction is not valid, as it would be changing the scope of $x$. In order to avoid this, an $\alpha$-reduction must be performed before the $\eta$-reduction.

Comment: The $\alpha$-reduction point is subtle - thank you for clarifying this.