# zero raised to power zero in Church encoding

Tags: exponentiation, natural-numbers, lambda-calculus

In Church encoding of the natural numbers in lambda calculus raising zero to the power zero gives the answer zero. Does anybody know of an encoding where the answer is 1?

Comment: no, it gives $1$ as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
(λm.λn.n m) (λf.λx.x) (λf.λx.x)
⇒   (λn.n (λf.λx.x)) (λf.λx.x)
⇒   (λf.λx.x) (λf.λx.x)
⇒   λx.x
```

Another different calculation ((\m.\n. ((n (\m.\n.\f. (m (n f)))) f x))(\f.\x.x)(\f.\x.x)):

```
(λm.λn.n (λi0.λi1.λi2.i0 [i1 i2]) f x) (λi0.λi1.i1) (λi0.λi1.i1)
⇒   (λn.n (λm.λi0.λi1.m [i0 i1]) f x) (λi0.λi1.i1)
⇒   (λi0.λi1.i1) (λm.λn.λi0.m (n i0)) f x
⇒   (λi0.i0) f x
⇒   f x
```

Calculations done using: http://www.cburch.com/lambda/index.html

Comment: Which is not a Church numeral at all, is it? So, can we conclude that $0^0$ is undefined in the context of Church encoding?

Comment: @DanielR I am slightly confused by it myself now. I calculated it again using a different approach, which does indeed result in 1.

Comment: $\lambda x.x$ and $1$ are equivalent under $\eta$-expansion

Comment: I'm confused. In "Constructive Foundations for Functional Languages" http://www.academia.edu/456528/CONSTRUCTIVE_FOUNDATIONS_FOR_FUNCTIONAL_LANGUAGES it says λx.x is the zero object

Comment: Ping @mercio. $\;$

Comment: the zero object is $\lambda f. \lambda x. x$. Meanwhile, $\lambda x. x =_\alpha \lambda f.f =_\eta \lambda f. (\lambda x. f x) = 1$

Comment: thanks for the clarification. Just found "For example, the combinators (λy.λx.yx) and (λy.y) are observationally equivalent" on another answer[link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65622/whats-the-point-of-eta-conversion-in-lambda-calculus). Out of interest could you not also eta expand to λf.(λx.x) f which I really don't understand? why dont you put as answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @William When you address a user who is not the author of the answer or question, you can add a @ and the user name. This way, the user is made aware of your comment by getting a notification in their inbox. This may help your attempt to reach out to mercio.

Comment: @mercio sorry, new here. please see comment before last